# Error when trying to create GCP organization sink using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to create an organization sink using TF,
when running the command as shown in the documentation everything works https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/central-log-storage . (shown commented in the snippet below)

```
# gcloud logging sinks create all-audit-logs-sink \
# logging.googleapis.com/projects/logs-test-project/locations/global/buckets/all-audit-logs-bucket \
#   --log-filter='logName:cloudaudit.googleapis.com' \
#   --description="All audit logs from my org log sink" \
#   --organization=12345 \
#   --include-children


resource "google_logging_organization_sink" "my-sink" {
    name   = "tf-central-logging-sink"
    description = "Organization wide audit logging sink"
    org_id = data.google_organization.default.id

    destination = "logging.googleapis.com/projects/${local.logging_project_id}/locations/global/buckets/${local.logging_bucket_id}"

    include_children = true 
    filter = "logName:cloudaudit.googleapis.com"
  }
```

I get the following Error:

```
│   <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
│   <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
│   <p>The requested URL <code>/v2/organizations/organizations/815724849902/sinks?alt=json&amp;prettyPrint=false&amp;uniqueWriterIdentity=true</code>
 was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
│ 
│ 
│   with google_logging_organization_sink.my-sink,
│   on main.tf line 25, in resource "google_logging_organization_sink" "my-sink":
│   25: resource "google_logging_organization_sink" "my-sink" {
│ 
╵
```

I tried searching online for errors when creating a sink using TF, only found a permission denied error, I made sure i have the correct permissions ,also verified by being able to create the resource via CLI . (same identity used to run the TF).

Anyone seen this before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your provider configuration?

Comment: Hi @MarkoE
```
provider "google" {
    project = local.provider.project_id
    region  = local.provider.region
    zone    = local.provider.zone
}
```
I have not configured any specific version, but the one i am using is
hashicorp/google v4.38.0

Comment: And did you remove the one previously created using the CLI?

Comment: @MarkoE The one I created via CLI is named differently , can there only be one additional sink besides the two default ones?

Comment: Not really sure, I am not familiar with GCP, but that could be an issue if true.

Comment: Thanks, I don't believe its related because you can create multiple sinks with different filters and different destinations.